# WatiN - Switch to Browser windows based on element inside the browser say a Heading1 element

Tags: c#, watin

Has anyone implemented different methods to switch across browser windows in WatiN?
Current methods which are supported are :

`browserType`

Type: `System..::.Type`

The WatiN browser type to attach to.
`constraint`

Type: `WatiN.Core.Constraints..::.Constraint`

The `Constraint` of the browser window to find. `Find.ByUrl()`, `Find.ByUri()`, `Find.ByTitle()` and `Find.By("hwnd", windowHandle)` are supported.

I want to create a method which switches to a new popup either based on some element present inside the browser page or using hwnd which should be unique.
This method should ideally support both the browsers IE and Firefox.

Use Case:

Suppose I have one browser window open and after clicking a link and on a button it opens two new popup / browser windows. Both are having same title but the contents are different.
One window is having heading1 text as "My Heading One" and other is having heading2 text as "my Heading two".
Now I want to switch to second popup browser window which heading heading2 element.
Is it possible to use `Browser.AttachTo(browser.getType(), Find.By.....);` ??

Answer (score 0):

As per your use case, once you click on a link, a new pop/window is opened. If you are sure that for Parent window there would be H1 elements (for verifying/attaching) and for child's window H2 elements (verifying/attaching). So you need to create H1 and H2 elements as shown below.

```
[ElementTag("h1")]
public class HeaderLevel1 : ElementContainer<HeaderLevel1>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Div"/> class.
    /// Mainly used by WatiN internally.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="domContainer">The DOM container.</param>
    /// <param name="htmlH1Element">The HTML h1 element.</param>
    public HeaderLevel1(DomContainer domContainer, INativeElement htmlH1Element) : base(domContainer, htmlH1Element) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Div"/> class.
    /// Mainly used by WatiN internally.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="domContainer">The DOM container.</param>
    /// <param name="finder">The HTML h1 element.</param>
    public HeaderLevel1(DomContainer domContainer, ElementFinder finder) : base(domContainer, finder) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name of this Watin element.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "HeaderLevel1";
    }
}
```

Similarly for H2, you can do the same. For IE, you can use,
IECollection browsers = IE.InternetExplorers(), 
which returns you the IE collection and for each, get the H2 elements count and then try to attach using the current title. I am not very sure how we can achieve this in FF, but there must be a way.

Thanks,
Sham_

Comment: I want a generic solution. I know using IECollection this is possible but I basically want to use lambda expression like `browser = Browser.AttachToNoWait(MyBrowser.getType(), Find.ByMyBrowser( browsr => browsr.H1("Heading One").Exists));` Do you think this is possible?

Comment: How? Mean to say how can I extend `Find` to get MyBrowser or `Browser` with lambda? `Find.ByBrowserElement( elem => elem.Text == "Heading One")` or `Find.ByBrowser( browser => browser.H1(Find.ByText("Heading One")).Exists) ` . Is it possible for you to put it as answer to my question?

Comment: Using your code (Lambda expression exactly) is not possible as IE and Firefox implementations are different. But it is possible to use different method as shown below.

   <pre> <code> `public void AttachToOtherBrowser(Constraint newFindBy)
 {
   switch (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Browser"])
   {
     case "IE":
        Util._browser = IE.AttachTo(Util._browser.GetType(), newFindBy);
        break;
     case "FF":
        Util._browser = FireFox.AttachTo(Util._browser.GetType(), newFindBy);
        break;
   }
 }`